# Can’t play SoundEffects with Monogame 3.2 for Windows 7 Desktop (DirectX)

Tags: c#, monogame

For some reason I cannot get Monogame to play any sounds through SoundEffect or SoundEffectInstance.
With a workaround I can get Songs to play, but still not SoundEffects or SoundEffectInstances.

If I run my example below through “native XNA” everything works fine.

I’m using:
Monogame 3.2 for Windows Desktop (DirectX)
Windows 7
Visual Studio Express 2013

Example:

```
    SoundEffect effect;
    SoundEffectInstance instance;
    Song song;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Load sound, no errors and the objects get filled with data.
        effect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("myWavFileAsSoundEffect"); // Loaded with ContentProcessor = "Sound Effect - XNA Framework" 
        song = Content.Load<Song>("myWavFileAsSong"); // Loaded with ContentProcessor = "Song - XNA Framework"
        instance = effect.CreateInstance();

        // Set volume to 100%, just in case
        SoundEffect.MasterVolume = 1.0f;
        MediaPlayer.Volume = 1.0f;
        instance.Volume = 1.0f;
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            // Play instance. Nothing happens.
            instance.Play();

            // Play effect. Nothing happens.
            bool success = effect.Play(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            // success is true

            // Play song.
            try
            {
                // Error
                // HRESULT: [0x80004002], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_NOINTERFACE/No such interface supported]
                MediaPlayer.Play(song);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Play the song again
                // Plays fine
                MediaPlayer.Play(song);
            }
        }


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong? Why can’t I play any SoundEffects or SoundEffectInstances?

Comment: Looks like a bug in MonoGame. I'd definitely raise this issue on their github page if it's not already there.

Comment: I've been having the same problem, seems like a bug on their side :/

Comment: I've been having problems playing a song file in DirectX builds as well. I ended up switching to an OpenGL project and everything worked fine. I just used the raw .wav file and added the extension when loading the content:
Content.Load<Song>("myWavFileAsSong.wav")

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 and I'm not having any issues.

Comment: Same problem here. Adding .wav does not help either. I can load and play a SoundEffect in Xamarin on mac, but not in Visual Studio on windows...

Comment: I have upgraded to MonoGame 3.4 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem but on Windows 10. The solution for me was to reinstall Directx. 
Webinstaller: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35&84e4d527-1a2f-c70a-8906-a877ec4baada=1

Hope this helps

Comment: I had this problem too on Windows 10. This fixed it, thank you very much! My Pong clone would not be complete without the classic 8-bit sound effects.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was having problem with when added .wav files.But when I added .xnb files which is generated after building the XNA project(files are in bin\content folder),errors gone.Could you please try with xnb files.